# Node JS Returning Without Promise Fulfilling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am hoping this is an easy questions, and I just missed something simple. I have a chain of promise returning functions that flow using .then(). My final function takes the data I return, and formats into the correct format, which is then passed back to the client. The issue I am having (I think), is that the server sends the ff variable to the client before the promise from the formatting function is getting resolved. What confuses me, is that when I log the ff variable, it is logging with all the data as expected.

Any thoughts on why this is occurring, what I am doing wrong, and most importantly how to resolve this?

```
app.get("/subData", function(req, res) {
    getConnection().then(function() {
        return getSQL();
    }).then(function(sql) {
        return executeQuery(sql);
    }).then(function(data) {
        return formatData(data);
    }).then(function(ff) {
        console.log(ff);
        res.status(200).send(ff);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("ERR:");
        console.log(err);
        res.status(405).send(err);
    });    
});
```

Here is the final format data function:

```
function formatData(data) {
    var finArr = Array();

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        data.rows.forEach(function(row, fin) {
            var tempArr = Array();

            row.forEach(function(itm, pos) {
                var ttl = data.metaData[pos].name;
                var val = itm;

                tempArr[ttl] = val;
            });

            finArr.push(tempArr);

            if(fin + 1 == data.rows.length) {
                resolve(finArr);
            }            
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a promise for a simple synchronous operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with promises resolving properly. The issue was in how I was formatting my data to be sent back to the client. I was building an array of associative arrays with the following code. When it was sent to the client, it was being sent as a blank array of arrays.

```
data.rows.forEach(function(row, fin) {
        var tempArr = Array();
        row.forEach(function(itm, pos) {
            var ttl = data.metaData[pos].name;
            var val = itm;
            tempArr[ttl] = val;
        });
        finArr.push(tempArr);    
    });
    return finArr;
```

What I needed to do was send the data as an array of objects and then convert it to an array of arrays on the client side. By adjusting my code to this, the data properly passed over as I needed.

```
data.rows.forEach(function(row, fin) {
    // Change From var tempArr = Array() to var tempArr = {} to initialize new Object
    var tempArr = {};

    row.forEach(function(itm, pos) {
        var ttl = data.metaData[pos].name;
        var val = itm;

        tempArr[ttl] = val;
    });
    finArr.push(tempArr);    
});
return finArr;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear that one of your promises isn't resolving.  Why make the `resolve()` call in your `formatData()` method conditional? Why not just let the loop run out?

```
function formatData(data) {
    var finArr = Array();

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        data.rows.forEach(function(row, fin) {
            var tempArr = Array();

            row.forEach(function(itm, pos) {
                var ttl = data.metaData[pos].name;
                var val = itm;

                tempArr[ttl] = val;
            });

            finArr.push(tempArr);    
        });
        resolve (finArr);
    });
}
```

Indeed, you don't need a Promise here at all, because it's a synchronous operation. And, it's OK to use synchronous operations in `.next()` chains. Like this.

```
function formatData(data) {
    var finArr = Array();

    data.rows.forEach(function(row, fin) {
        var tempArr = Array();
        row.forEach(function(itm, pos) {
            var ttl = data.metaData[pos].name;
            var val = itm;
            tempArr[ttl] = val;
        });
        finArr.push(tempArr);    
    });
    return finArr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I have removed the promise, but it is still exhibiting the same behavior. The console is properly logging the data, but the client is still receiving an array of blank arrays.